# Using T-SQL to determine Subnet Mask from CIDR

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, subnet, cidr

I have a CIDR in the form of 192.168.1.1/32 and I need to be able to convert the /29 into the traditional subnet notation of 255.255.255.0 (I might have the subnet wrong). This needs to be done in T-SQL (MS SQL) and its also very unlikely I will be allowed to use CLRs or any other non-standard 2008r2 features.

The end result is I need to convert 192.168.1.1/32 to 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.0 where /32 can be any valid /X

Comment: What do you want as the answer? Is the result to be stored as a string? One column with both the address and the mask?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I'm not understanding the problem, but why is it complicated?

```
select
  case 
    when right(cidr,2) = '24' then mask = '255.255.255.0'
    when right(cidr,2) = '25' then mask = '255.255.255.128'
    when right(cidr,2) = '26' then mask = '255.255.255.192'
    when right(cidr,2) = '27' then mask = '255.255.255.224'
    when right(cidr,2) = '28' then mask = '255.255.255.240'
    when right(cidr,2) = '29' then mask = '255.255.255.248'
    when right(cidr,2) = '30' then mask = '255.255.255.252'
    when right(cidr,2) = '31' then mask = '255.255.255.254'
  end as mask
from atable
where  patindex(cidr,'%/[0-9][0-9]') > 0
```